# SASS variables set for height (if height)

Tags: css, sass

Can I set variables inside of an if / else conditional in SASS?

- If the height is > 500, then `overflow-y` is auto.
- If the height is < 500, then `overflow-y` is not displaying in class.

I don't know how to write code so I need your help. I want to set `overflow-y` as per condition in SASS.

```sass
.demo {
    if @height > 500px {
        overflow-y:auto
    } else @height {
        overflow:visible
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `@height` is a sass variable, the doc say you can do it :
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/structure#operations

If you want to do css conditional depending of the height of `.demo`, i don't think it's possible in full css.